# Mongodb Aggregation with collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

a list of products is attached to a program.
There are multiple programs with same list of products and same name.
What I need is to aggregate data to get a list of distinct programs with associated programs array.

What I did is :

```
  Program.aggregate( [
   { $group: {
        _id: "$name", count: {$sum: 1} ,  products : { $addToSet : "$products.asin" }}
   }])
```

But with that query i get multiple arrays with same data :

> [ {
>   _id: "Météo", count: 681, 
>   products: [ [ "**B003I4DS22**", "**B00BH56GXM**", "B006SMNQWI", "B008QZQRIK", "B00AC1ZLJC", "B0064X7FVE", "B009M4SGUG",
>   "B0013K6C6M", "B002JM0DEK", "B0009ENA2W" ]
>   , [ "**B003I4DS22**", "**B00BH56GXM**", "B006SMNQWI", "B008QZQRIK", "B0064X7FVE", "B00AC1ZLJC"
>   ], [ "B003I4DS22", "B00BH56GXM", "B0064X7FVE", "B008QZQRIK",
>   "B006SMNQWI", "B00AC1ZLJC", "B009M4SGUG", "B0013K6C6M", "B002JM0DEK",
>   "B0009ENA2W" }]

what I want is :

> [ {
>   _id: "Météo", count: 681, products: [ [ "B003I4DS22", "B00BH56GXM", "B006SMNQWI", "B008QZQRIK", "B00AC1ZLJC", "B0064X7FVE", "B009M4SGUG",
>   "B0013K6C6M", "B002JM0DEK", "B0009ENA2W"]]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a distinct list of `product.asin` values, you'd want to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `products` arrays in your documents before grouping them:

```js
db.test.aggregate( [
   { $unwind: '$products' },
   { $group: {
        _id: "$name", 
        count: {$sum: 1} ,  
        products : { $addToSet : "$products.asin" }}
   }])
```

Comment: Actually doesn't that just count all the elements in the array? The set would be distinct but the count would not be, and would actually represent the total elements in the array. Unless you added some other stages to actually do this that is.